# How to use strings with JavaScript Typed Arrays

Tags: javascript, html, typed-arrays

I've come across a problem in that I don't see a way to easily convert strings to typed arrays, and converting from typed arrays to strings appears to be a real pain requiring a manual char code conversion for every byte. Is there any better methods to convert strings to typed arrays or vise-versa?

**Example:**

I have a UTF8 encoded string, "Something or other", and I want to write it to an ArrayBuffer in length then string format.

Comment: What kind of conversion do you want exactly? Can you give us an example?

Comment: Typed Arrays are only implemented for numbers. You somehow need to convert a string into numbers, i.e. `str.charCodeAt` and `String.fromCharCode`. You can make it more convenient, though: http://jsfiddle.net/ACXM7/.

Comment: Why do you want to store them in typed arrays at all? That sounds like you wanted to simulate the internal representation of a simple js string :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) and [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder), it was originally only implemented in Firefox, but has [since gained wider support](https://caniuse.com/textencoder). This two full years after your initial question :)

Fortunately, there exists a [polyfill](https://code.google.com/p/stringencoding/) that does the job.

```
var initialString = "Something or other";

var utf8EncodedString = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(initialString);

// utf8EncodedString is a Uint8Array, so you can inspect
// the individual bytes directly:
for (var i = 0; i < utf8EncodedString.length; ++i) {
    console.log(utf8EncodedString[i]);
}

var decodedString = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(utf8EncodedString);

if (initialString !== decodedString) {
    console.error("You're lying!");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should solve your problem

[How to use strings with JavaScript Typed Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153725/how-to-use-strings-with-javascript-typed-arrays)

JS Strings are stored in UTF-16 encoding where each character takes 2 bytes. String.charCodeAt returns these 2-byte Unicodes. This is how to read UTF-16 encoded strings from a DataView:

```
DataView.prototype.getUTF16String = function(offset, length) {
    var utf16 = new ArrayBuffer(length * 2);
    var utf16View = new Uint16Array(utf16);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        utf16View[i] = this.getUint8(offset + i);
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, utf16View);
};
```

and these functions to convert string to and from arraybuffer

```
    function ab2str(buf) {
       return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
     }

    function str2ab(str) {
       var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
       var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
       for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
         bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
       }
       return buf;
     }
```

Comment: The link at the tops links to the here question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use external libraries, you can take a look at [jDataView](https://github.com/jDataView/jDataView) which supports reading [strings](https://github.com/jDataView/jDataView/wiki/Strings-and-Blobs) in different encodings from a TypedArray and handles endianness conversion as well.