# AngularJS - Displaying multiple PNG images from buffer received from $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, png, blob, arraybuffer

I am getting stream of information from $http API call. And I use to extract information from it as follows in angular JS,

AngularJS Controller:

```
ThumbnailsFactory.getThumbnails().then(
  function(res) {
    var FourBytes = 4;
    var TwoBytes = 2;
    var offsetVal = 0;

    var dataView = new DataView(res, offsetVal);
    // 4 bytes for signature
    var sign = dataView.getInt32(offsetVal);
    offsetVal += FourBytes;
    //  2 bytes for UnsupportedVersionException() - must be 1
    var version1 = dataView.getInt16(offsetVal);
    offsetVal += TwoBytes;
    // 2 bytes for ThumbnailMultiStream - must be 1    
    var thumbnailstream = dataView.getInt16(offsetVal);
    offsetVal += TwoBytes;
    //  2 bytes for UnsupportedVersionException() - must be 1        
    var version2 = dataView.getInt16(offsetVal);
    offsetVal += TwoBytes;

    // Total number of images
    var cnt = dataView.getInt32(offsetVal);
    offsetVal += FourBytes;

    // Skip 4 bytes to past the offset vector position.
    offsetVal += FourBytes;

    // Read IDs
    var ids = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
      var id = {
        id: dataView.getInt32(offsetVal),
        img: ""
      };
      ids.push(id);
      offsetVal += FourBytes;    
    }

    // Skip past the offset vector
    for(var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
      offsetVal += FourBytes;    
    } 

    // ThumbnailMultiStream
    for(var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
      var l = dataView.getInt32(offsetVal);
      offsetVal += FourBytes;  
      var img = "";      
      // Read image data
      for(var j = 0; j < l; ) {
        var read = l - j;
        if(read > 4096) read = 4096;
        img = new DataView(res, offsetVal, read);
        offsetVal += read;

        if(img < 0) {
          // error
          break;
        }
        j += read;
      }

      ids[i].img = "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(img);
      ids[i].buffer = JSON.stringify(img);
    }

    $scope.sign = sign;
    $scope.version1 = version1;
    $scope.thumbnailstream = thumbnailstream;
    $scope.version2 = version2;
    $scope.thumbnails = ids;
  },
  function(error) {
     // error
  }
);
```

AngularJS Service:

```
thumbnailsFactory.getThumbnails = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var url = "http://192.168.1.61:4321/thumbnails";
  var requestConfig = {
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'install_id': 'TiTnMzWAjEK6TbaB2gA55g'
        },
        timeout: 3000,
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    };
    $http(requestConfig).then(
        function(res) {
            deferred.resolve(res.data);
        },
        function(error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;       
  }
```

HTML:

```
    Sign: {{ sign }}<br>
    Version check 1: {{ version1 }}<br>
    Kind = {{ thumbnailstream }}<br>
    Version check 2: {{ version2 }}<br>      
    Images: <br>

    <div ng-repeat="tn in thumbnails">
        <p> ID: {{ tn.id }} </p>
        <p> Image Buffer: {{ tn.buffer }}</p>
        <img ng-src="{{tn.img}}" alt="Loading...{{ tn.img }}"/>
    </div>
```

Output:

```
Sign: 2074848171
version check 1: 1
Kind: 3
version check 2: 1

Images:

    ID: 31
    Buffer: { "byteLength": 557, "buffer": { "byteLength": 2021 },      "byteOffset": 38 }
Loading...data:image/png;base64,W29iamVjdCBEYXRhVmlld10=
    ID: 32
    Buffer: { "byteLength": 1422, "buffer": { "byteLength": 2021 }, "byteOffset": 599 }
Loading...data:image/png;base64,W29iamVjdCBEYXRhVmlld10=
```

Buffer extraction is correct, as I am getting the next ID of Image correctly while reading buffer. But the problem is I am not getting the PNG image correctly.

How can I get the Image from that Buffer? Please help me guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your use of btoa is wrong. You need to extract the string from the dataView.

To do that, everything is here : [How to use strings with JavaScript Typed Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153725/how-to-use-strings-with-javascript-typed-arrays)

I extracted this piece of code for you :

```
DataView.prototype.getUTF8String = function(offset, length) {
    var utf16 = new ArrayBuffer(length * 2);
    var utf16View = new Uint16Array(utf16);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        utf16View[i] = this.getUint8(offset + i);
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, utf16View);
};
```

Then, eveything should work fine.

Comment: I hope it works. Can you please elaborate on where and how should I use this method? btoa(img) or btoa(getUTF8String(img)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should just do "data:image/png;base64," + getUTF8String(img) . This should probably work.

Comment: I replaced "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(img)" with "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(img.getUTF8String(0, img.byteLength)). And it works fine now.